# max record using MAX function or DESC in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to fetch latest user from User table.Which one of the below queries has best performance in Postgres for doing this.?

```
Select MAX(u.id) from User u;
```

or

```
Select u.id from User u order by desc limit 1;
```

Comment: You should try on your data and your system.  However, if you have an index on `user(id)`, then I would expect both to be very fast.

Comment: Max would be faster.

Comment: Check the execution plan

Answer (score 0):

This is an elaboration of the comment.

If you have an index on `user(id)`, then both formulations should use that index.  I'm pretty sure they would have essentially the same execution plan.

If you don't have a (b-tree) index, then I think the `max()` version will be faster.  I think it will read the data once and extract the `max()` in a single pass.  The `order by` will have to sort all the records.

Sometimes databases have some very specific optimizations that might apply (such as an optimization that might recognize a special case with `limit` and `order by`).  I don't think any apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on your PostgreSQL version, but I tested the two approaches on a representative table (which is what you should do):

```
explain analyze select max(id) from versions;
                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.21..0.21 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.034..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.08..0.21 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
           ->  Index Only Scan Backward using index_versions_on_id on versions  (cost=0.08..98474.35 rows=787172 width=4) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                 Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning time: 0.143 ms
 Execution time: 0.062 ms
(8 rows)

explain analyze select id from versions order by id desc limit 1;
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.08..0.21 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan Backward using index_versions_on_id on versions  (cost=0.08..98080.76 rows=787172 width=4) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
         Heap Fetches: 1
 Planning time: 0.099 ms
 Execution time: 0.044 ms
(5 rows)
```

This was from 9.4.5, on a unique index on a table with 860,000 rows.

This showed that the order by technique was marginally faster, but for me it is not enough to decide that you should use that method -- performance is not everything, and I prefer the semantics of the max() approach.